# How to go through files in directory in ascending order

Tags: python, file-io

I currently have a certain file in my directory that I am going through in Python and iterating using os.listdir.

The files in this directory are stored as numbers like this:

36
51
72
117
138
255
.
.
.
.
1095
2000
3001
4004

Instead of iterating in this order, the files iterate according to the first number in the file. So instead of going ascending order it would go 1095->2000->3001->36->5001->51 and so on. How can I ensure that I iterate in the correct ascending order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
sorted(os.listdir('path/to/dir'), key=int)
```

To ensure that the order is numerical do `key=int`. The function [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) returns a list, to iterate over them just do:

```
for files in sorted(os.listdir('path/to/dir'), key=int)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have your file names stored in a list for iterating over, if you do, all you have to do is:

```
fileList.sort()
```

then iterate over it as you have been.

Comment: I don't have them stored as a list. Im just going through them normally from my directory. like this: for files in os.listdir(game_directory):

Comment: Understood. I think for future reference, it would be nice if you posted a code snippet of exactly how you're implementing your code. In this case though, it sounds like Daniel Mesejo answered your question

Comment: Understandably so. Will do that. Thank you!